# Where to place an executable Perl script?

Tags: linux, unix, shell-script, perl, solaris

I'm now planning a solution that has to call a script that's running on a Linux \UNIX host.
I'd prefer to place that script in a folder that exists in all kinds of Linux and UNIX. This helps me to guide the users just to copy the script into the same folder.

I'm looking for that folder...

More info:

- The script should be accessible (+rx) to all users on that machine
- The script is static and does not generate output files It should
- It should work for Linux and UNIX (all kinds), especially Red-Hat, Solaris and
  AIX

Where should I place the script? /opt? /var?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The script goes in [`/usr/local/bin`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the script to run like a command. Place the script in any location defined in the PATH variable. To view the data in your PATH variable.

```
echo $PATH
```